# Can you increase the amount of potions made per day with the following?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, crafting, potions

> A character is also allowed to create up to four potions in a single day (if they cost up to 250 gp or less), rather than the usual one magic item per day, usually limited to one day per 1000 gp limit.

Is this amount set in stone?

The [Artisan](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/drop-dead-studios/the-artisan/) class has abilities the can reduce creation cost and creation time by 25%+, with a feat further reduce creation cost by 58% and creation time up to 35%+. Does that increase potion creation? If not does the trait Awakened from Stasis do anything for it?

> **Awakened from Stasis**
>
> Benefit(s) As a side effect of your stasis, you gain all the benefits of 8 hours of sleep in only 2 hours. This allows a spellcaster who must rest to prepare spells to do so after only 2 hours, but does not allow a spellcaster to prepare spells more than once per day.

Answer (score 4):

The statement that you can brew up to four potions in a day is a rule like any other: it supersedes more general rules (such as the usual minimum of one day for an item that costs 1,000 gp or less), and is superseded by more specific rules, if they exist. It is entirely plausible for someone to write something that says you can brew more than four potions in a day.

But it would have to *say that*. Other effects that speed up crafting times don’t affect that rule, since it forms a minimum baseline independent from the calculated crafting time. So artisan does not help. While something certainly *could* help, I am not aware of any features that do so.

And no, Awakened from Stasis does absolutely nothing for you; Awakened from Stasis only affects sleeping times, absolutely nothing else.

Comment: [Mythic Brew Potion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-feats/mythic-brew-potion-mythic/) could work, but it is both 3rd Party and using the mythic rules.